# add a "." to a textbox when the user enters 3 characters

Tags: excel, vba

How can I add a "." to a textbox when the user is writing and the user enters 3 characters?

```
Private Sub txt_nome_usuario_Change()

    If Left(txt_nome_usuario, 3) Then

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need to add a dot after each sequence of three characters?

Comment: yeah man, i need that

Comment: Cool, I do still think that you left out a lot of your code since I cannot see where you attempt to add any of your requirements into your shared code. There is not ending to the `If` statement so it seems you didn't copy all.

Comment: I didn't end it because I'm waiting for someone to tell me how I introduce the "." to finish the if

Comment: What set of characters does the user write? May surrogate pairs and other Unicode 
specialities be included? Are dots allowed as user entered characters? Should they be counted as ordinary user entered characters? what if user removes characters by editing after dots already auto-added?

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub txt_nome_usuario_Change()
    If Len(txt_nome_usuario) = 3 Then
        txt_nome_usuario = txt_nome_usuario & "."
    end if
End Sub
```

This only works one time, it could be expanded like this: (not the most effiecient code)

```
Private Sub txt_nome_usuario_Change()
    If Len(txt_nome_usuario) = 3 Then
        txt_nome_usuario = txt_nome_usuario & "."
    End If
    
    If Len(txt_nome_usuario) = 7 Then
        txt_nome_usuario = txt_nome_usuario & "."
    End If
    
    'etc.
End Sub
```

You could also try something like this:

```
Private Sub txt_nome_usuario_Change()

Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To 9
    If Len(txt_nome_usuario) = 3 + 4 * i Then
        txt_nome_usuario = txt_nome_usuario & "."
    End If
Next i
    
End Sub
```

But, using any of these methodes will create a problem when you want to delete the newly created dot, as once you delete it, it will automatically create a new dot.

Comment: Better method for checking if a dot is required: `If Len(txt_nome_usuario.Value) mod 4 = 3 Then`: this will trigger on 3, 7, 11, 19, et cetera

Comment: Correct, I'm not used to using "mod" but you are correct @Chronocidal

Answer (score 2):

This will always ensure that the textbox will have a "." every 3 characters:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
            
    If Len(TextBox1.Value) > 3 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        
        Dim tempInput As String
        tempInput = TextBox1.Value
        tempInput = Replace(tempInput, ".", "")
        
        Dim finalInput As String
        Do While Len(tempInput) > 3
            finalInput = finalInput & Left$(tempInput, 3) & "."
            If Len(tempInput) > 3 Then tempInput = Mid$(tempInput, 4)
        Loop
        
        If Len(tempInput) > 0 Then finalInput = finalInput & tempInput
        
        TextBox1.Value = finalInput
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

There will be an issue though if the user enter "." themselves.

Comment: The only issue I could find is that you are not able to enter "." yourself, but it doesn't give rise to any other issue?

Comment: @Nick - Not that I'm aware of, entering "." themselves will cause it to be eaten up so it's not possible to have say "ab..cde.ghi"

Comment: `Application.EnableEvents = False` would have similar effect to your `EventInProgress = True`

Comment: @Chronocidal - Yes that's true! I totally forgot about `EnableEvents` just now

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example how I handled TextBoxes that should take an IP address as input. You can easily adjust that to your needs if this is not exactly what you need. This is meant to show the concept how to solve such things.

Add the following class module named `TextBoxIP`

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents m_TextBoxIP As MSForms.TextBox
Private m_EditMode As Boolean

Public Property Set TextBox(ByVal oTextBox As MSForms.TextBox)
    Set m_TextBoxIP = oTextBox
    m_TextBoxIP.Font = "Consolas"
End Property

' add dots automatically each block of 3
Private Sub m_TextBoxIP_Change()
    If m_EditMode Then Exit Sub
    
    With m_TextBoxIP
        Dim AmountOfDots As Long
        AmountOfDots = Len(.Value) - Len(Replace$(.Value, ".", vbNullString))

        If Len(.Value) = 3 And Right$(.Value, 1) <> "." Then
            m_EditMode = True
            .Value = .Value & "."
            m_EditMode = False
        ElseIf AmountOfDots > 0 And AmountOfDots < 3 And Right$(.Value, 1) <> "." Then
            Dim Pos As Long
            Pos = InStrRev(.Value, ".")

            Dim RightPart As String
            RightPart = Mid$(.Value, Pos + 1)
            If Len(RightPart) = 3 And Right$(RightPart, 1) <> "." Then
                m_EditMode = True
                .Value = .Value & "."
                m_EditMode = False
            End If
        ElseIf AmountOfDots > 3 Then
            m_EditMode = True
            Do While AmountOfDots > 3
                .Value = Left$(.Value, InStrRev(.Value, ".") - 1)
                AmountOfDots = Len(.Value) - Len(Replace$(.Value, ".", vbNullString))
            Loop
            m_EditMode = False
        End If
        
        ' if more dots then 3 cut off from the end (can happen on insert)
        m_EditMode = True
        Do While AmountOfDots > 3
            .Value = Left$(.Value, InStrRev(.Value, ".") - 1)
            AmountOfDots = Len(.Value) - Len(Replace$(.Value, ".", vbNullString))
        Loop
        m_EditMode = False
        
        ' validate each block to be <= 255
        Dim Blocks() As String
        Blocks = Split(.Value, ".")
        
        Dim iBlock As Long
        For iBlock = LBound(Blocks) To UBound(Blocks)
            If IsNumeric(Blocks(iBlock)) Then
                If Blocks(iBlock) > 255 Then Blocks(iBlock) = 255
            Else
                Blocks(iBlock) = Val(Blocks(iBlock))
                If Blocks(iBlock) > 255 Then Blocks(iBlock) = 255
                If Blocks(iBlock) = 0 Then Blocks(iBlock) = vbNullString
            End If
        Next iBlock
        
        m_EditMode = True
        .Value = Join(Blocks, ".")
        m_EditMode = False
    End With
End Sub


' allow only valid ip chars and control input in 4 groups devided by dots
Private Sub m_TextBoxIP_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
    'Debug.Print KeyCode
    Dim SelPos As Long
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    
    With m_TextBoxIP
        ' get block of cursor
        Dim CursorPos As Long
        CursorPos = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(1, .SelStart)
    
        Dim BlockStart As Long
        BlockStart = InStrRev(.Value, ".", CursorPos) + 1
        If BlockStart <= 0 Then BlockStart = 1
        
        Dim BlockEnd As Long
        BlockEnd = InStr(CursorPos + 1, .Value, ".") - 1
        If BlockEnd <= 0 Then BlockEnd = Len(.Value)
        
        Dim Block As String
        Block = Mid$(.Value, BlockStart, BlockEnd - BlockStart + 1)
                
        Select Case KeyCode.Value
            Case vbKey0 To vbKey9, vbKeyNumpad0 To vbKeyNumpad9:
                If Len(Block) >= 3 And .SelLength = 0 Then
                    KeyCode.Value = 0
                End If
                
            Case vbKeyLeft, vbKeyRight:
            Case vbKeyInsert:
            Case vbKeyDelete:
                If .SelLength <> Len(.Value) Then
                    If .SelStart < BlockStart - 1 Or .SelStart + .SelLength > BlockEnd Then
                        KeyCode.Value = 0
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                    
                    If .SelStart < Len(.Value) Then
                        If Mid$(.Value, .SelStart + 1, 1) = "." And Mid$(.Value, .SelStart, 1) <> "." Then
                            m_EditMode = True
                            SelPos = .SelStart
                            
                            .Value = Left$(.Value, .SelStart + 1) & Mid$(.Value, .SelStart + 3)
                            .SelStart = SelPos + 1
    
                            KeyCode.Value = 0
                            m_EditMode = False
                        End If
                    End If
                End If

            Case vbKeyHome, vbKeyEnd:
            Case vbKeyReturn, vbKeyEscape:

            Case vbKeyTab, vbKeyCapital:
            Case 190: 'dot
                Dim AmountOfDots As Long
                AmountOfDots = Len(.Value) - Len(Replace$(.Value, ".", vbNullString))
                
                ' allow only 3 dots and if there is no dot left cursor
                If Mid$(.Value, .SelStart, 1) = "." Or AmountOfDots >= 3 Then
                    KeyCode.Value = 0
                End If
                
            Case vbKeyBack:
                If .SelLength <> Len(.Value) Then
                    If .SelStart < BlockStart - 1 Or .SelStart + .SelLength > BlockEnd Then
                        KeyCode.Value = 0
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                    
                    If .SelStart > 0 And .SelLength = 0 Then
                        If Mid$(.Value, .SelStart, 1) = "." And Mid$(.Value, .SelStart + 1, 1) <> "." Then
                            m_EditMode = True
                            
                            SelPos = .SelStart
                            If .SelStart = Len(.Value) Then
                                .Value = Left$(.Value, wf.Max(0, .SelStart - 2)) & Mid$(.Value, .SelStart + 1)
                            Else
                                .Value = Left$(.Value, wf.Max(0, .SelStart - 2)) & Mid$(.Value, .SelStart)
                                .SelStart = wf.Max(0, SelPos - 2)
                            End If
                            KeyCode.Value = 0
                            m_EditMode = False
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
                
            Case vbKeyV, vbKeyC: ' allow copy paste
                If Not Shift = 2 Then ' allow olny Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V
                    KeyCode.Value = 0
                End If

            Case Else: ' disallow all other keys that are not handled above
                KeyCode.Value = 0
                Exit Sub
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Add to your user form

```
Option Explicit

Private m_CollectionOfIPboxes As Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set m_CollectionOfIPboxes = New Collection
    
    ' make Me.TextBox1 a IP box
    m_CollectionOfIPboxes.Add New TextBoxIP, "TextBox1"
    Set m_CollectionOfIPboxes("TextBox1").TextBox = Me.TextBox1
    
    ' make Me.TextBox2 a IP box
    m_CollectionOfIPboxes.Add New TextBoxIP, "TextBox2"
    Set m_CollectionOfIPboxes("TextBox2").TextBox = Me.TextBox2
End Sub
```

[image]

Features:

- The dots are automatically generated and removed.
- Editing in between is possible
- Prevents that more than 3 digits per block are entered
- Prevents adding multiple dots (eg after dot is inserted automatically pressing the dot on the keyboard is ignored)
- Only numbers and dots can be entered
- Set font of TextBox automatically to `Consolas` for monospaced numbers
- Validation of each block to be <=255
- Copy/Paste from clipboard is possible (invalid IPs get corrected).

Comment: What made you think the question is related to IP addresses, and therefore should allow also 1 or two characters only between points?

Comment: @TomBrunberg The first 2 comments after the question made me assume that. What made you assume the code does not accept 1 or 2 characters between dots? Because it does accept less than 3 digits as you clearly can see in the animation. Nevertheless, if the OP does not need it for IP addresses he can easily adjust the code and it gives a good start.

Comment: Those two comments still do not imply IP addresses, only that there might be many of these 3-char groups. Also, nothing implies only numbers for those 3-char groups (or in fact anything about character sets). **I did not say that your code doesn't accept 1 or 2 chars groups.** I said that there is nothing in the question that indicates that 1 or 2 chars should be accepted between dots. The question only talks about 3-char sequences. **The question simply leaves too much for speculation and guessing, and therefore it should be closed until improved.**

Comment: @TomBrunberg As I said. The OP obviously had no idea. I had done something similiar already. So it is up to him to adjust this to his needs. This is (as always) not meant as an copy/paste ready to use code. Thinking and adjusting is still recommended. • It might not be exactly what the OP wants but still I consider it as an helpful example how things like this can be solved. I added an introduction sentence to make that more clear.

Comment: Ok, let's leave it at that.

Answer (score 0):

This version has a couple of caveats, which might be deal-breakers for you

1. It does not add the "." until *after* you overflow (i.e. when you type the 4th character, not after the 3rd). This can be changed at/after the `txtFormat = Left[…]` line
2. It does not let the user type "." as part of their string

```
    Private Sub txt_nome_usuario_Change()
        Dim txtValue As String, txtFormat As String
        
        txtValue = Replace(txt_nome_usuario.Value, ".", "") 'Remove existing "."s
        If Len(tmpText)<1 Then Exit Sub 'No text, no action
        
        txtFormat = WorksheetFunction.Rept("@@@.", 1 + Int(Len(txtValue) / 3)) 'Create initial Format text
        txtFormat = Left(txtFormat, Len(txtValue) + Int((Len(txtValue)-1) / 3)) 'Trim Format to exact length
        
        txtValue = Format(txtValue, txtFormat) 'Apply the formatting
        
        If txtValue = txt_nome_usuario.Value Then Exit Sub 'No change, no action
        
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'Do not re-trigger the event as a result of this change
        txt_nome_usuario.Value = txtValue 'Apply the formatted text
        Application.EnableEvents = True 'Treat future changes as genuine
    End Sub
```